# Loading Slick2D texture inside a jar file

Tags: java, slick2d

I exported my Game as a jar and the Texture loading won't work anymore. I have a class that provides the Spritesheet as a static variable

```
public static Texture SPRITESHEET = loadTexture("res/texture/spritesheet.png");

public static Texture loadTexture(String path) {

    try {
        return TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",new FileInputStream(path));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
```

When I try to run the jar I get the Exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: res\texture\spritesheet.png (The system cannot find the path specified)

I unpacked the jar to check if the res folder is in there and it was. Do I have to make specific setting to tell the program where to start looking for the folder?

I used JarSplice to build a fat jar with for lwjgl and slick.

Comment: try this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);

Comment: this doesn't work because I want to make it static

Comment: `<class_name>.class.getResourceAsStream(path);` is just as good.

Comment: This gives me an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

Comment: The root for the resource path is the `classpath`. It is likely you are getting a `null` at the moment because the resource is not on the `classpath`. for instance `class_name.class.getResourceAsStream(class_name.class)` returns the class file as does `class_name.class.getResourceAsStream(/my/package/name/class_name.class)`

Comment: I found out that the problem is the static usage in some way. Is there  a way to fix this?